# How do I setup Task Scheduler in Windows 7 to compress a folder using 7-Zip File Manager?

Tags: windows-7, compression, scheduled-tasks, 7-zip, file-management

I would like to get 7-Zip Manager to zip my wwwroot folder on a weekly basis. Is it possible to automate this with Windows 7 Task Scheduler, and if so, what are the exact steps to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need to create a Windows Batch file that will do that actually ZIP, and then schedule this in Task Scheduler to run on a weekly schedule.

The 7-Zip command-line samples are available [here](http://dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples) and  a step by step guide to Windows 7 Task Scheduler is available [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/12444-task-scheduler-create-new-task.html). Lastly to create a batch file use notepad and create a new file with a .BAT extension as follows

```
@echo off
[7zip command line here]
```

Save the file somewhere on your drive and point the scheduled task to it. Complete details on batch files are available [here](http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm).

Comment: Ahan, any idea on how do I create this sort of batch file? Thanks!